# Can I use XpsDocument class in a Windows Form app

Tags: windows, forms, xpsdocument

I'm trying to convert an XPS document to a BMP so that a C# Windows Forms app using MODI can read it, because my understanding is that MODI cannot read XPS files, only .tif and .bmp

I can't seem to locate the XpsDocument class.

Can anyone tell me how to incorporate this into my Windows Forms app?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to ReachFramework.dll, and use the [System.Windows.Xps.Packaging namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.packaging.aspx)

Comment: Great! You may take Saturday off. I guess Sunday too. Thanks!